# Make FAQ narrower and more exact

Tags: discussion, faq

> Sports medicine is a branch of medicine that deals with physical
>   fitness, treatment and prevention of injuries related to sports and
>   exercise.

The FAQ of Fitness and Nutrition (F&N) says that the site is for

- improving your exercise performance or technique
- choosing a training program
- nutrition as it relates to exercise
- gear and gadgets used during exercise
- achieving physique milestones
- injury prevention

The FAQ suggests me that the site should be within Medicine -site. The name of the site is narrower than the claims in the faq. Possibly "Sports Medicine" could match better the name of the site at the moment.

I would simply remove at least the sentence "injury prevention" from the FAQ. The first sentence "improving your exercise performance or technique" belongs to "Sports" -exchange site. The third sentence also gets a big space to the site, I would clarify it somehow, perhaps adding some clarification before the first word.

Answer (score 4):

I think that improving exercise performance is an integral part of fitness, that exercise technique is crucial to fitness, and that injury prevention is indispensable to fitness.

It's OK that the FAQ covers topics that aren't part of the site title. I don't think that the site's name can or should explicitly include all the topics the site covers.

I am opposed to using Sports Medicine as a template for our site or FAQ for a few reasons:

- We aren't medical professionals and don't want to practice medicine on the site
- Just because Sports Medicine deals with fitness and injury doesn't mean that a site about fitness that includes questions about injuries is a medical or sports-medicine site. Baseball involves running and throwing, but I'm not playing baseball just because I run sprints and throw a javelin.

Comment: ...`"physical fitness professionals, athletes, trainers, and those providing health-related needs"`, sorry but the first bullet point is vague as `"those providing health-related needs"` do contain med/etc people. Sorry I am getting tired to artistic reading of FAQ.

Comment: @hhh While a medical professional might participate in the site, we do not want (nor do they want, I imagine) them to do so in their professional capacity. We might value their contributions strongly, but this is not a site for diagnosing or treating disease. Preventing injury is not the same as medical practice.